# How to create table using .install file in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, schema

I am new to drupal, working on custom module, here is my .install file code, but its not creating table in database when I install module. can anyone please tell me where I am wrong

```
<?php
    function make_application_schema()
    {
        $schema['make_master'] = array(

     'description' => 'Make master table',
     'fields' => array(
       'make_id' => array(
        'description' => 'make id primary key auto increment',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
      'make_name' => array(
        'description' => 'Make name',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => '100',
        'not null' => TRUE,
     ),
    'make_status' => array(
      'description' => 'check make status',
      'type' => 'int',
      'size' => 'tiny',
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
  ),
  'primary key' => array('make_id'),
);
return $schema;
}

  function make_application_install()
  {

  }

  function make_application_uninstall()
  {

  }
```

Comment: I have find and fix issue I change name of functions where I am using "make_application" remove "application" from all 3 functions

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your module? When you are installing and you use hook_schema, you should name your function like this:

my_module.module

In my_module.install

```
function my_module_schema () ....
```

And... after that, this should be work :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to install your database 'make_master' you have to call drupal_install_schema with your **module name**:

```
drupal_install_schema('make_application');
```

Comment: This is now a discouraged practice in Drupal 7 (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/7.x)

Answer (score 0):

according to your question I think you have forgot to call `drupal_install_schema` function. Here are updated `make_application_install` and `make_application_uninstall` of your make_application.install.

```
function make_application_install() {
// Use schema API to create database table.
   drupal_install_schema('make_master');
}


function make_application_uninstall() {
// Remove tables.
   drupal_uninstall_schema('make_master');
}
```

---

*NOTE*
The tables won't install on module enable, they will only install on first-time install. First, disable the module, then click the 'uninstall' tab, select the module, and uninstall it (note: if your module doesn't have a hook_uninstall() function, it won't appear here - make sure you have added this function). Then, click the list tab, and re-enable your module. This is a first-time install, and the tables will install.

Either that or use the devel module, enable the development block and then use the 'reinstall modules' link in the block.

You can refer this link for more info : https://www.drupal.org/node/811594

Comment: Thank you, I have add that 2 lines in install & uninstall function and follow the same way for disabled and uninstall module. But still its not working